# Problem with passive form

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am trying to solve an exercise where you have to rewrite sentences into passive form. I am having a problem with these sentences:

> Someone empties our bins every week.

submit: **Our bins** are emptied by someone every week.

> People grow lots of varieties of tea in India.

submit: **Lots of varieties** of tea are/were grown in India by people.

Where am I doing wrong?

*Please note: the **bold text** is the book tip.*

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: 'Lots of varieties of tea are grown in India by people' is correct but sounds unnatural, 'people' being weak as part of a by-phrase. 'Lots of varieties of tea are grown in India by people owning small to medium businesses' (with a 'respectable' agent) or 'Lots of varieties of tea are grown in India' (with no agent) sound natural. But this becomes a guessing game: 'What sort of answer does Sir/Miss expect?'

Comment: @JohnLawler the question is "Where am I doing wrong?". Sorry for not being clear

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for the suggestion. I am using a book website so I can't write more words than those present.

Comment: Sorry, but _Where am I doing wrong?_ is ungrammatical, and (if I decode it right) contains a presupposition that there's some other error in the sentence(s), but you didn't say what you thought it was. We have no idea here what you're doing or why you're doing it, so asking what's wrong is not very productive.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am sorry. I am going to explain what is the context. I am studying English using an English book used in school. I was doing this exercise where the request is to rewrite the sentences in the passive form. I've solved some of them. To complete the exercise I have to solve two sentence that I wrote in this post. I wrote the sentences and my incorrect proposed solution. So, I was asking where am I wrong and in a way to learn. Thank you

Comment: As has been said to you "Where am I doing wrong?" is not correct, it is not idiomatic; however, you could say "Where am I doing a mistake?". The readers of your question would like to know how you know that something is wrong, if not what it is. In fact what is wrong has been explained in  user Edwin Ashworth's comment as best can be done. There is little else to be said.

Comment: Thank you to explain me how to write a good question on this platform. I hope to learn more from all of you. I knew that I was wrong because the book website set my answer as "not valid". So I tried to change them but i didn't find a good solution. This is why I created this question writing the sentence to rewrite and my submission.

Comment: So are you saying that you are doing this exercise on the Internet and that the site tells you that your answers are incorrect, but does not explain why? If so, it would have helped to state that within the question; as the question is formulated, it is unclear why you think that your answers are incorrect.

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually, *Where am I doing wrong?* is grammatical.  He works from  5 different cities and he only "does wrong" in one of them -- which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the passive voice serves well is to place the emphasis on **the activity done** rather than on the agent doing the activity.

In fact, the passive often deletes the agent, so prepare to **subtract words**, not to add them:

> Our **bins are emptied** every week.
>
> Lots of **varieties** of tea **are grown** in India.

But who empties the bins? Wrong question, unless you are hiding the agent (You don't want to say, you don't know, or it's unclear.) The sentence might be saying to forget retrieving valuables in bins, as ours get emptied weekly.

So who grows those Indian teas? (Wrong question, unless...) Of course people (farmers) do, but the sentence is focusing on the **varieties of tea** and nothing else.

Comment: It is true that vague, uninformative subjects of active sentences, such as *someone* or *people* are often omitted when the sentences are turned into the passive (indeed, the reason for using the passive form is often that it makes this possible), and it is a reasonable guess that the authors of the exercise probably expected the students to do this. That, however is a matter of style, rather than grammar in the strict sense. If the exercise merely asked that the sentences be transformed into their passive equivalents, and nothing else, then the OP's answers were correct.